# Why my UILabels don't update any more after putting it in a scrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have created a calculator which was updating several UILabels after clicking on button. It worked fine until I cut and paste into a scrollview.

When clicking, in debugger the messages to set text for Label are still sent but nothing updates, there's not even any error message shown.

why ?

Comment: Are you using Interface Builder? It's possible the labels have lost their references.

Comment: I'm using XCode 4 Visual Builder. How to regain these references ? If I lost them shouldn't the compiler cry ?

Comment: possible that the connections to your outlets have lost

Comment: You're right thanks It lost owner I recreated it now it works : you can put as answer and I will select it as good answer if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making use of interface builder the labels could've lost their 'references' (the links between the label and what you've defined the `IBOutlet` as in your header).

Right click on one of the labels and confirm the correct referencing outlets are shown and that there are no yellow warnings triangles.

Answer (score 1):

possible that the connections to your IBOutlets UILabel to your file owner have lost. that happens usually when you try to copy/cut and paste objects in interface builder